Egypt reciter (qari)
Anyone familiar with this particular reciter (Qari) may be Egyptian based on pronunciation.
For certainly, I'd like to know.
Could you please inform me his name and where I can locate the links to his recitation videos on YouTube full Surah? Anywhere on the internet audio files? Thank you.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IloWk2YTz-s
